# Как получить "связанные" записи из разных баз данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-orm

Есть таблица А (находится в бд `default`) и таблица В (находится в бд `logs`). В таблице В есть поле а_id, в котором записан айди на соответствующую запись с таблицы А, которая маппится на другую бд.
Есть какие-то нативные джанговские способы сджоинить к списку записей с таблицы В соответствующие записи с таблицы А?

*Django v3.2*